# WP admin ajax Pagination issue

Tags: ajax, pagination

Hello i am using ajax to filter my custom post type based on categories by ajax after ajax filter i am getting my desire result but after ajax call pagination not working.

this is giving me this error **wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?paged=2**

Here is my Code:
*JS Code:*

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('#filter').submit(function(){
            var filter = $('#filter');
            $.ajax({
                url:ajaxurl,
                data:filter.serialize(), // form data
                type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
                beforeSend:function(xhr){
                    filter.find('button').text('Applying Filters...');
                },
                success:function(html){
                    filter.find('button').text('Apply filters');

                    $('.content-list').empty();
                    $('.content-list').append(html);

                    // $('.content-list').hide();
                    // content-list

                    // $('#response').html(data);
                    console.log(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

**PHP code**

```
function brose_opinion_filter(){

    if( isset( $_POST['check_list'] ) ){

        $items = ($_POST['check_list']);

        // Paged query Number Pagination
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
        $i=0;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'articles',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $items,
                ),
            ),

        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

        <!-- Pagination -->
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <ul class="cd-pagination move-buttons custom-icons">
                <?php
                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                    global $wp_query;

                    echo paginate_links(array(
                        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages=$query->max_num_pages

                    ));

                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Sort By -->
        <!-- <form id="sortby"> -->
            <label>Sort By</label>
            <select name="sortby" id="sortby">
                <option value="date">Date</option>
                <option value="month">Month</option>
            </select>
        <!-- </form> -->
        <!--END Sort By -->

    <?php

        if( $query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    ?>

        <li>
            <div class="content-item">
                <a class="content-img">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $query->post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                </a>
                <div class="content-text">
                    <h2 class="content-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <?php
                        global $post;
                        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($query->post->ID);

                        if(!empty($tags)){
                            foreach($tags as $tag){
                                echo '<a class="tag" href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <hr>
                        <small>Annual Review and Forecast · Latest release <?php echo get_the_date( 'j M Y' ); ?></small>
                    <hr>
                    <p><?php  echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 50);?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="cta cta-small cta-grey">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    <?php

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();


        else :
            echo '<h2>No posts matched !</h3>';
        endif;

    }

    die();
}  

add_action('wp_ajax_customfilter', 'brose_opinion_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customfilter', 'brose_opinion_filter');
```

**Here i want to display the result**

```
<div class="columns medium-9">
                <ul class="content-list">


                    <?php

                        // Paged query Number Pagination
                        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
                        $i=0;
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'articles',
                            'posts_per_page' => 1,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'orderby' => 'post_date',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => $ptax,
                                ),
                            ),

                        );
                        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    ?>

                        <!-- Pagination -->
                        <div class="medium-12 columns">
                            <ul class="cd-pagination move-buttons custom-icons">
                                <?php
                                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                                    echo paginate_links(array(
                                        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                                        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                                        'total' => $query->max_num_pages
                                    ));
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Sort By -->
                        <!-- <form id="sortby"> -->
                            <label>Sort By</label>
                            <select name="sortby" id="sortby">
                                <option value="date">Date</option>
                                <option value="month">Month</option>
                            </select>
                        <!-- </form> -->
                        <!--END Sort By -->

                        <!-- Custom Loop -->
                        <?php
                            if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                                $i++;   
                        ?>

                            <li>
                                <div class="content-item">
                                    <a class="content-img">
                                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $query->post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="content-text">
                                        <h2 class="content-title">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </h2>
                                        <?php
                                            global $post;
                                            $tags = wp_get_post_tags($query->post->ID);

                                            if(!empty($tags)){
                                                foreach($tags as $tag){
                                                    echo '<a class="tag" href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        <hr>
                                            <small>Annual Review and Forecast · Latest release <?php echo get_the_date( 'j M Y' ); ?></small>
                                        <hr>
                                        <p><?php  echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 50);?></p>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="cta cta-small cta-grey">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </ul>


                <!-- Ajax Response -->
                <!-- <ul id="response"></ul> -->

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `get_query_var` is never going to return anything on an Ajax request, because there is no query to parse. You need to pass the page number you want the same way you pass the form data.

Comment: @Milo can you please give me some example of the same that would be really helpful for me.